# Webdriver.IO not able to download file continuously using Webdriver.io

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I'm using **[Webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/)** to download a file continuously

**I tried the following code:**

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
      //   waitforTimeout: 1000000
    }
};
webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()

    .url('https://xxx')
    .setValue('#username', ‘xxx@gmail.com’)
    .click('#login-submit')
    .pause(1000)
    .setValue('#password’,’12345’)
    .click('#login-submit')
    .getTitle().then(function(title){
     console.log('Title was: ' + title);
    })
    .pause(20000)
    .getUrl().then(function(url){
      console.log('URL: ' + url);
    })
    .getTitle().then(function(title){
     console.log('Title was: ' + title);
    })
    .click("a[href='/wiki/admin'] button.iwdh")
    .getUrl().then(function (url) {
        console.log('URL after settings ' + url);
    })
    .pause(3000)
    .scroll('div.jsAtfH',0,1000)
    .click("a[href='/wiki/plugins/servlet/ondemandbackup/admin']")
    .pause(10000)
  .click('//*[@id="backup"]/a')
  //.pause(400000)
 .end();
```

**Note:** The file size is 7GB and how long it will take to download is depend upon the network so instead of using pause() and timeout()  is there any way to do it using webdriver.io or node.js ?

Comment: Priyanka,  I'll answer your question, but I need more info from you. WebdriverIO has multiple types of `timeouts` (see **[here](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/timeouts.html)**), each with its own purpose. How are you launching your tests? (via which command) Are you using a test framework to write/run the tests and if so, which? (e.g: Cucumber, Jasmine, Mocha). You might be using the wrong tool for the job. Also that file size is obnoxious.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, your current task (`waiting for a HUUUUGE file to download`) is not a common use-case when it comes to Webdriver-based automation frameworks, **WebdriverIO** included. Such frameworks aren't meant to download massive files.

---

First off, you're confusing the `waitforTimeout` value with WebdriverIO **test timeout**. Your test is timing out before the `.pause()` ends.

Currently you're running your tests via the WebdriverIO test-runner. If you want to increase the test timeout, you have to use a different test framework (**[Mocha](https://mochajs.org/)**, **Jasmine**, or **Cucumber**) and set its `timeout` value to w/e you find appropriate. Going on, I recommend you use **Mocha** (coming from an ex-**Cucumber** guy).

You will have to install **Mocha**: `npm install --save-dev wdio-mocha-framework` and run your tests with it. Your test should look like this afterwards:

```
describe("Your Testsuite", function() {

  it("\nYour Testcase\n", function() {
    return browser
      .url('https://xxx')
      .setValue('#username', ‘xxx@gmail.com’)
      .click('#login-submit')

      // rest of the steps

      .scroll('div.jsAtfH',0,1000)
      .click("a[href='/wiki/plugins/servlet/ondemandbackup/admin']")
      .pause(10000)
      .click('//*[@id="backup"]/a')
  )}
)}
```

Your config (**wdio.conf.js**) should contain the following:

```
framework: 'mocha',

mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 99999999
}
```

As a side-note, I tried waiting a very long time (`> 30 mins`) using the above config and had no issues what-so-ever.

Let me know if this helps. Cheers!

Comment: var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var jasmine = require('jasmine');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};
describe(" Testsuite", function() {
  it(" Testcase", function() {
    it('code', function () {
    browser.url('https://xxx');
    browser.setValue('#username', 'xxx@gmail.com');
    browser.setValue('#password', 'xxx');
    browser.submitForm('#login-submit');
    browser.click('//*[@id="backupLocation"]/a');
});
  });
});

Comment: when i am running this getting error - describe not defined.  What would be the best framework to download large files using Nodejs.

Comment: Hey @Priyanka, currently @work with plenty on my plate, but I'll get back at you as soon as I get some spare time. I think you can do it w/o Mocha/Jasmine/Cucumber as well, but it's more hackish. Also you need to install Mocha package for WDIO to make that error go away: `npm install --save-dev wdio-mocha-framework` from your project root.

Comment: When i am giving timeout in "wdio.conf.js" file it's not able to downlaod file it's closing the session but by giving .pause(2000000) in  webdriver.io code it's able to download file of 7GB. What is the use of timeout in "wdio.conf.js"  file if it's kicking out the session without downlaod?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on a download button in your browser and you close your browser then your download will be also closed. If you are owning the website where you click on the download button then try to rewrite your code that you have a download able url. Then you can search for a module or way to download files from http url. If you are not the owner and you cant find a url in the href then you can maybe get the generated download url from the network section at your inspector.

Also I never heard that a browser gets closed after timeout? Maybe it comes from webdriver.io I never let my chrome so long open with webdriver.io
You can try to make a workaround use Intervall each 1 Minute as example and then use a webdriver.io command to don´t timeout.

Answer (score 0):

**I know** it's very old question but I wanted to answer question from comment (and have no such possibility yet). But I will answer main question too.

> When i am giving timeout in "wdio.conf.js" file it's not able to
> downlaod file it's closing the session but by giving .pause(2000000)
> in webdriver.io code it's able to download file of 7GB. What is the
> use of timeout in "wdio.conf.js" file if it's kicking out the session
> without downlaod?

So this timeout is related to elements state during the test run. So it "determines how long the instance should wait for that element to reach the state".
https://webdriver.io/docs/timeouts.html - this can help. But to answer the question too:

There are more many timeouts such test deals with. Like iamdanchiv wrote for this you should try using one of automatically supported frameworks like Mocha or Jasmine.
IMO right now the easiest way would to do the quick fresh setup using CLI provided by WDIO:
https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted.html
Where you can just simply pick the additional framework you want to use. I would suggest using Jasmine and Chromedriver for this. Than in your wdio.conf.js you can change this part:

```
  waitforTimeout: 10000,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    // Jasmine default timeout
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
    //
    },
```

To something that works for you. Or you can use boilerplate projects from wdio page like this one:
https://webdriver.io/docs/boilerplate.html

**But that's not all!** Still you will have to create some method or function that checks for the file. So check where do you download the file or make it download where you want to and then create a method that uses some kind of wait:
https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil.html

```
browser.waitUntil(condition, { timeout, timeoutMsg, interval })
```

So you can set the timeout either here or in wdio.conf in   'waitforTimeout'. Inside this method condition you can use node filesystem (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to check the state of the file.

This can be helpful to get through waiting for file condition:
https://blog.kevinlamping.com/downloading-files-using-webdriverio/